# Reading/importing .tpk maps into R or QGIS and use as shapefile

Tags: r, arcgis, qgis, r-sf

Is it possible to import a ***.tpk*** map file either in ***R*** or ***QGIS*** and use it as a shapefile? I need the coordinates of specific locations in the ***.tpk map*** that could be extracted with a shapefile map. I do not have access to ArcGIS.

Grateful for any guidance!

For additional information about .tpk, please see: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/sharing/overview/tile-package.htm

Comment: Got one we can download and try? I'm saying "R can't do this (yet)" because GDAL doesn't understand the files from here: https://github.com/consbio/tpkutils/tree/main/tests/data  - you could try using that python code to convert to something GDAL does understand...

Comment: Also note the comment in that repository about ESRI changing the format (10.1 vs 10.3). They are always moving the goalposts.

Comment: Thanks for the python package info. Here you have a .tpk file. Would be great if R could read it as shapefile, definitely a project that goes way beyond my R skills: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10jfFw4ovfdfnw3qnLVsJjMSZQ8HvjTDG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: These are raster data rather than vector data so you're not going to be able to read this "as a shapefile" if by that you mean as lines and polygons. Its gridded images, with different maps at different resolutions. The python code can create the map at any given resolution, but R interprets all resolutions as global maps, hence at zoom 17 to see your study area the raster is millions x millions. This might be croppable given the bounds, but its still not "shapefile" vector data.

Comment: Thanks for the insights and your time. Do you think that with the python package you mentioned, I could get the centroids of those maps, or more generally, specific coordinates of points in those maps? Would you mind sharing potential approaches I could try myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I've done:

First convert the tpk file to mbtiles using the tpk conversion utility
from https://github.com/consbio/tpkutils

```
tpk export mbtiles 04010588800801.tpk 04010588800801.mbtiles
```

gdalinfo shows a few things about the mbtiles file:

```
$ gdalinfo 04010588800801.mbtiles 
Driver: MBTiles/MBTiles
Files: 04010588800801.mbtiles
Size is 23418224, 20166662
...
Metadata:
  ZOOM_LEVEL=17
...
  minzoom=0
  maxzoom=17
...
```

We could load this into R, but that size is enormous and I can't find a way to select a given zoom level and a given range based on the valid tiles. This I can do with `gdal_translate` on the command line or via the `gdalUtils` package to create a GeoTIFF for a given zoom level, using `USE_BOUNDS=NO` to constrain the output to only where tiles exist:

Command line:

```
gdal_translate -oo ZOOM_LEVEL=17 -oo USE_BOUNDS=NO 04010588800801.mbtiles zoom17.tiff
```

`gdalUtils` package:

```
gdal_translate("04010588800801.mbtiles","z17.tiff",
     oo=c("USE_BOUNDS=NO","ZOOM_LEVEL=17"))
```

Reading and then plotting this level 17 RGB image can then be done:

```
> z17 = raster::stack("z17.tiff")
[ignore CRS warnings...]
> plotRGB(z17)
```

[image]

Note this is quite a high resolution image so you can't read the labels, but if you zoom in (or load into QGIS and interact there) you can read the labels. Here's an extreme zoom into level 17 in QGIS showing the limits of the resolution:

[image]

Remember this is only raster image data so if you want the coordinates of those points you'll have to create a new layer in QGIS and manually create a point data set over the imagery. If this is what you want then I strongly suggest you try and get vector data from the supplier and not have to do all this!

The other zoom levels might be useful to you so convert them using the `gdal_translate` procedure above. As you go out you lose detail, and below level 13 you just get the overview maps.

Level 16:

[image]

Level 13:

[image]

Level 12:

[image]

## Update

A slightly more direct way to read from the `.mbtiles` file. Use the `stars` package which does allow you to pass GDAL options:

```
s = stars::read_stars("04010588800801.mbtiles",
    options=c("USE_BOUNDS=NO","ZOOM_LEVEL=17"), proxy=FALSE)
rs = as(s,"Raster")
raster::plotRGB(rs)
```

The `proxy=FALSE` is needed otherwise when converting with `as(..,"Raster")` the output reverts back to the 20166662x23418224 dimension of the full global level 17 zoom raster. Possible bug in stars somewhere. Anyway, this gets you the zoomed rasters without having to use `gdal_translate` anywhere.

Comment: How about `library(terra); r = rast("04010588800801.mbtiles", opts=c("USE_BOUNDS=NO","ZOOM_LEVEL=17"))`  ?

Comment: @RobertHijmans "Unused argument" error with opts. 1.3-22... got the latest from CRAN (1.4.22) and that runs but it doesn't seem to be getting the right zoom level every time - levels 15,16,17 look like they are all level 15. They have the expected higher resolution but seem to be rescaled zoom=15 tiles. Bug report?

Comment: Can you share the mbtiles file?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/weaiqu7fkia3fbp/04010588800801.mbtiles?dl=0 and let's take discussion elsewhere?

Answer (score 4):

Building on @Spacedmans's answer and using the `tpk` file that he created, I show a range of zoom levels using the `terra` package

```
library(terra)
plotm <- function(zoom, e=NULL) {
    # read file with GDAL options
    r = rast("04010588800801.mbtiles", opts=c("USE_BOUNDS=NO", paste0("ZOOM_LEVEL=",zoom))); 
    # declare the RGB channels
    RGB(r) <- 1:4
    plot(r, ext=e)
}
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
x <- lapply(6:14, plotm)
```

[image]

Here using an extent to zoom in a bit to be able to better see the differences at the highest resolutions

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
e <- ext(3935206, 3935662, 1085835, 1086294)
x <- lapply(14:17, plotm, e=e)
```

[image]

And that looks the same in ArcMap with the original `tpk` file.